# Can I add a Column to my *view* on a Postgres database with an updating timestamp each time the row is modified?

Tags: postgresql, zapier

I want to be able to add a date that the cell in a row was modified (it is a boolean so from false to true) and i want it to override the last date? I want to use this as the trigger for a zap and all i have found so far is that I can add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS "current_timestamp" to my select statement within my create or replace view command. This then doesn't update when i make changes to a row and keeps the original date. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your table structure and queries u have tried so far

Comment: I have added current_timestamp() to my select statement and that auto populates when my view is updated and then does not amend when i make any further changes. the tables themselves do not contain a timestamp, which is where the problem is i think

Comment: First off your timestamp doesn't exist on your table, thus it **cannot** be persisted. Neither does it have anything to do with any update, it will show the timestamp of when the select executed. Secondly it sounds as dynamic refresh of the display. This ***does not*** happen, to update the display you must re-execute the select.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL database stores ID of transaction for every row and may store transaction-commit timestamps if the configuration parameter `track_commit_timestamp` is set to TRUE

if it is set to TRUE then you can select the row-last-modification-moment by using function `pg_xact_commit_timestamp` withing system column `xmin`

the query would be like this:

```
  SELECT some_columns, pg_xact_commit_timestamp(t.xmin) AS change_moment
   FROM thetable AS t
```